# get value of column using jquery when clicked on a row

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview as follow:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSentDate" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NumberWithText" HeaderText="Number" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NumberWithMask" HeaderText="Number"
                            ReadOnly="true" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

I want to get the text of NumberWithText whenever user click on the row. I have following jquery which gets it by column but I want to get just that column when user clicks on whole row:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%=gvSentDate.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function (e) {
                $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
            });

            $("#<%=gvSentDate.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
                var selTD = $(e.target).closest("tr");
                alert(selTD.text());
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following code for the same:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=gvSentDate.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hover(function (e) {
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        });

        $("#<%=gvSentDate.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").click(function (e) {
            var selTD = $(e.target).closest("tr");
            alert(selTD.text());

    $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index());
        });
});
```